# Why is the filesize of my disk twice as small in 'df -h' compared to 'lsblk'?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, hard-disk, smb

I just bought and installed a 4TB NAS HDD to use as a SMB Share. Through windows it only shows me a capcity of 2TB instead of 4, which I found out is because Samba uses the 'df -h' command, whereas I use 'lsblk'.

**lsblk output**

`sda      8:0    0   3.7T  0 disk`

`└─sda1   8:1    0   3.7T  0 part /media/Harddrive1`

**df -h output**

`/dev/sda1            2.0T  166G  1.8T   9% /media/Harddrive1`

Why is it that partition sda1 is bigger on lsblk than it is on df -h? And how would I go about using the full capacity of my new harddrive?

**EDIT**
This is the output of my gdisk -l

[image]

Here is the output of parted -l

[image]

Comment: Did you use MBR(msdos) partitioning which was designed in the early 1980's when MB was large, GB essentially not even used, and TB so large it would never be used for a  PC. So MBR has a 2TB limit. Drives over 2TB must use gpt partitioning to use entire drive. Post this: `sudo parted -l`  or `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`

Comment: what file system is on sda1? (lsblk -f)

Comment: @oldfred I posted the outputs. Did I mess up the partitioning of the drive?

Comment: @UncleBilly ext4

Comment: It shows as gpt and 4TB, 3.6 formatted. You have sdc & sdd as MBR, but since smaller drives that still works, just gpt is somewhat better. Not sure why df not showing larger size.